昨日急にデータベースが動かなくなりました
Accessでいつも通りにシステムを開くと以下のエラーが表示されます。
エラーコード
実行時エラー'3048':
これ以上データベースをひらくことはできません

コードは以下になります。
Private Subコマンド5_Click()
Dim STRTITLE, STMSG,MSG1, RMSG1
Dim db As Database 
Dim TB As Recordset 
Dim MySQL As String

Dim PassName As String
'PassName =C:¥Users¥user¥Desktop¥受注T”&”¥” 
    'PassName =”Z:¥TOMAC_受注T”&”¥”
PassName =”¥¥ 192.9.0.5¥share¥TOMAC_受注T”&”¥”
Dim MyName As String
MyName= Dir(PassName, vbNormal)

Do WhiIe MyName <> “”
 fname =  PassName & MyName
 I **Set db =  CurrentDb**
 MYSQL =”SELECT* FROM 吸上 WHERE ファイル名＝”＆”'”& fname &”‘”
 Set TB= db.OpenRecordset(MYSQL)
If TB.EOF Then


‘Debug.Print MyName
‘Kill PassName & “¥” & MyName
‘//—次のファイル名を返す
'MyName = PassName & “¥” & MyName
TB.AddNew
TB!［ファイル名］＝PassName & MyName
    TB! [日付］＝Date

TB.Update   
End If
MyName = Dir 
Loop
Forms!［フォーム1 ] ! [FS_吸上］．Requery
TB.Close

MsgBox”完了”,vbOKOnly + vbInforma.tion
End Sub 

Set db =  CurrentDbの部分が黄色マーカーで引かれています


お困りなのはなんとなくわかりますが、ご質問は何でしょう？

Copilotで尋ねたらこんな回答でした。原因：データベースの上限に達している, Officeの更新プログラムの影響, 対策：データベースの最適化, テーブルを複数のAccessファイルに分けてリンクすることで容量を分散させる, 実行するAccessファイルの保存場所を「信頼できる場所」に追加する, Officeのバージョンを戻す, ショートカットやAccessファイルから直接起動せず、Accessを起動してから対象のファイルを選択する 参考記事 MS Access　実行時エラー ’3048’ これ以上データベースは開けません, Access 「エラー3048：これ以上データベースを開くことができません」というエラーが表示される 詳細はご自分で確かめてみてください。

@kunif 回答はコメントではなく回答としてご投稿ください。

@nekketsuuu さん、いえAccessは1度も使用したことが無く検証も出来ませんのでコメントで情報を紹介するだけに留めます。

@kunif もしこの情報が未検証で正しさもよく分かっていないものなのであれば、それはコメントにも残すべきではありません。質問者さんや後からこの質問を見に来た方をただ迷わせるだけだからです。スタック・オーバーフローは素早く回答にたどり着けるナレッジベースとなることを目指しています。更に今回のコメントには未検証であるとも書かれていませんし、あたかも識者からの指摘のように見えてしまいます。　／　もし、なんとなく正しい気はするが検証が間に合っていないのであれば、そのことを書いた上で回答として投稿すべきです。部分的な回答や、条件付きの回答であっても、回答として投稿できます。後から間違いが判明した場合は、回答ごと削除すれば信用度も元に戻ります。

@nekketsuuu さん、なるほど回答と見間違うような文言にはせず、ヒントの提示にしておきますね。
